# Where could I collect UK participants for my survey?

Tags: survey, social-networks

I am looking for survey participants from the UK. Is there a place I can publish my survey in order to get UK participants?

Answer (score 4):

You could obtain paid participants from https://www.prolific.ac/

That site allows you filter by country.

The prices are reasonable, especially if your survey is short and you don't need too many participants.